# Using jQuery to pull info from a dropdown and creating a div with that info

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am running an AB split test that will modify a set of dropdown options for shipping options and creating four div containers with the shipping information inside them. The containers will be side by side boxes that are selectable using a button.  I am unable to modify the original html. I need to create this by modifying javaScript and an internal stylesheet.

Here is the html I have to work with:

```
<div id="carrierCommonDiv">
    <div class="nc_shipping_price_desc">Prices below reflect&nbsp;<span urlPath="/checkout/shipping_policy_popup.jsp?policy=shipping" relativeObj="shippingChargePopup" class="shippingLink3 popLink checkout_popLink">shipping charges</span> for your order.</div>
    <div class="nc_shipping_carrier_select">
        <select id="carrierCode" name="carrierCode">
            <option value="UG" shippingTotal="$13.95" selected="selected" desc="">Standard Ground ( $13.95 )</option>
            <option value="UTS" shippingTotal="$22.45" desc="">Third Day Ground ( $22.45 )</option>
            <option value="US" shippingTotal="$27.45" desc="">Second Day Air ( $27.45 )</option>
            <option value="UNN" shippingTotal="$37.25" desc="">Next Day ( $37.25 )</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Thoughts on how to solve this?

It currently looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/kBws6/ and should look about like this when completed: http://jsfiddle.net/mMqpG/

Comment: So what would you like the automatically created div to look like?

Comment: This is approximately what it currently looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/kBws6/

This is approximately what it should look like upon completion:http://jsfiddle.net/mMqpG/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started in jQuery.

### [Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/kBws6/3/)

First, find the select element and save it. Loop through each of it's children. In each loop, you can use `$(this)` to access all the information you'd need from each option and build some html. Insert it `after` the `select` element, and finally `hide` the original select element:

```js
var $select = $("#carrierCode");
$select.children("option").each(function() {
    var box = "<div class='shipOption' >"+$(this).text()+"</div>";
    $select.after(box);
});
$select.hide();
```

---

To add any **CSS rules**, you should specify the text and then `append` to the `head` element. Here's an example of how to do everything in-line, but preferably, you'd create a .css file and link directly to that.

```js
//TEST
$("head").append("<style type='text/css'>"+
                      ".shipOption {"+
                        "height:150px;"+
                        "width:100px;"+
                        "display:inline-block;"+
                        "border:solid 1px #333;"+
                        "text-align:center;"+
                        "float: left;"+
                      "}"+
                  "</style>");

//PROD
$("head").append("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='mystyle.css'>");
```

---

For **click event handling**, after you've modified the dom, just setup a listener for click events on anything with the `shipOption` class:

```js
$(".shipOption").click(function() {
    alert("You clicked "+$(this).attr("value"));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here's a start.

[**JS Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/rockyjreed/A4uma/)

If I'm reading your post correctly, it looks like you want to change how all the html displays without actually modifying the html.

Here's is a simple fiddle to show a method of adding/ removing those elements. All I'm doing is using a `forEach` function to iterate over a sliced array of the option elems and make new div elems, and then I use event delegation to listen for clicks to those new divs. I used vanilla JS - you don't really need to use jQuery for this kind of thing, but if you want to it's pretty much the same idea (just using $ selectors and `$(foo).on('click'...` instead).

The display isn't perfect, so you will want to mess around with that, but it should get you going.

Comment: Thank you. I will start with this. I like the var name controlling the css.  If the test works, the code will be modified more efficiently. The html/css will be modified by another developer.